# Springboot start failed from dao

Tags: spring-boot

Error message:

```
Description:

Field emailDao in com.example.demo.service.Email_userServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.Dao.EmailDao' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.Dao.EmailDao' in your configuration.
```

---

Following is my directory:

com.example.demo:

```
  Controller:

                  Class EmailController

       Dao:

                  Class EmailDao

       Entity:

                   Class Email

       Service:

                    Interface Email_userService

                    Class  Email_userServiceImpl
```

Class Demo6Application

---

the annotations I have added:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiCEx.png)

figure out this bug .

Comment: Usually when a bean is not found, this is because the class is not flagged as a potential bean OR it wasn't scanned by the projet.

For the first case, try adding `@Repository` at the top of the class.

For the second case, you should have a `@Configuration` class somewhere. Try adding something like that:

`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.package.path" })`

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.package.path" })`

Comment: I am adding a lot of information since I don't how thing are configured on your end

Comment: Yh，but where I need to add @Configuration

Comment: @Reene can you show us your EmailDao? Maybe the `@Repository` annotation is missing for that file or is not an interface extending from `JpaRepository<>`. Could you show us that file?

Comment: @Reene The class with the `@Configuration` annotation can be anywhere. Usually, it is a package called configuration or config. But yes, showing some code will help us a lot to help you. The best we can do right now is to throw shoot in the dark.